# Find a function that fits given data and generate data randomizing in x axis and y axis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have a sample data of time stamp, velocity. time stamp has length of 30 sec with 50 samples per sec. The plot of velocity and time looks like a sinusoidal function. I would like to write a function that fits the data and use to it generate 100 simulations of such data randomizing the frequency and peaks of velocity. How can I come up such function? Should I be using R or matlab to generate such data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider fitting a two-dimensional kernel density to the data and then sampling from this density.  Another quick and dirty approach might be to sample from the original data with replacement and add noise to both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.